# <link> and <script> paths not working (Nodejs ejs MVC)

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, model-view-controller, ejs

I have a problem with the paths of my `<link>` and `<script scr>`.
I am trying to respect an MVC structure and I have the `header.ejs` file included in `home_view.ejs`. But it does not work.
Even putting the paths absolute (which is orible I know) it doesn't work.

Here is my MVC structure :

[image: my structure]

`home_view.ejs` :

```
<%- include('header.ejs'); %>

blablabla

<%- include('footer.ejs'); %>
```

`header.ejs` :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/test.css"> <!-- not working -->

    <title><%= titre %></title>

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        header
    </header>
    <main>
```

`home_controller.js` :

```
'use strict';

let titre = 'Bonjour Nicolas';

const homeView = (req, res) => {
    res.render("home_view", { titre : titre });
}
module.exports =  { homeView };
```

Thanks in advance for those who will answer me.

Edit :

My `index.js` :

```
'use strict';

/* eslint-env node, es6 */

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4242;

app.use('/', require('./routes/home_route'));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`serveur démaré: localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: try to create the style folder outside the views folder and acces it via ../style/test.css

Comment: @Ctac I have already tried but without success

Comment: can you please provide your server.js code?have you setup the static path for assets and style etc? like this for example: app.use("/style",express.static(__dirname + '/style'));

Comment: @Ctac I hadn't configured a static path indeed.
Should the same be done for the "script src"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so your problem is you have not registered the static path for style sheets , so i would recommend you to put the style folder outside the views folder and then registere it in your index.js file as the mentioned in the comment:

```
app.use("/style",express.static(__dirname + '/style'));
```

this should work then.

The same needs to be done for your scripts

```
app.use("/script",express.static(__dirname + '/script'));
```